# Get specific strings from one long string

Tags: arrays, string, shell, split

I have an issue with my shell, I try to get some specific strings in a very long string.

The format of the string is:

```
Something(first:test, second:test2, third:test4, fourth:test4, fifth(Field(test:1, test2:test2,...)), Any1:test1, Any2:test3.
```

I want to get the string after `first`, `third` and `Any1`. I could easily split with `,` and get those as array values, but I can't predict in which position `Any1` will be, so I have to detect for a "`Any1`" value.

How can I do that?

Comment: What's your desired output from the example input you gave? It sounds like you want `test`, `test4`, and `test1`, but I'd rather not assume.

Comment: yes, you're correct the desired output is test, test4 and test1

Comment: Probable typo:  the input has *three* `(`s, but only ***two*** `)`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as stated does not impose conditions or constraints on the solution. On the other hand, it does mention shell ("I have an issue with my shell"). Here is a solution in shell (bash) using only a couple of standard Linux utilities: grep and cut. (But note we assume the availability of the -P switch in grep, which is not a valid assumption for all platforms, although it seems to be fairly common on Linux these days.)

```
$ cat -n solution.sh
     1  #!/bin/bash
     2
     3  grep -Po '\b(first|third|Any1):\w+' | cut -d: -f2
     4

$ cat infile.txt
Something(first:test, second:test2, third:test4, fourth:test4, fifth(Field(test:1, test2:test2,...)), Any1:test1, Any2:test3.

$ solution.sh < infile.txt
test
test4
test1
```

Answer (score 2):

Multichar `RS` probably won't work in all awks (*) but:

```
$ awk -v RS="[(,] *"  '            # record split at all the right places
BEGIN {
    a["first"];a["tird"];a["Any1"] # define the keywords we are interested in
}
split($0,b,":") && (b[1] in a) {   # split, match and score
    print b[2]
}' file
test
 test4
test1
```

*) Did work with GNU awk, mawk and Busybox awk but did not work with bwk awk.